# What is the etiquette for copying my own questions and answers from other QA sites to StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette, copyright, copycat-sites

I have been very active on Quora for about 5 months, but I'm very new to StackExchange. As such there's many questions and answers over on Quora relevant to questions on StackExchange.  If I want to copy a question here for more input or copying an answer to a relevant question, what etiquette is followed regarding citing the original entry?

BTW, it's my understanding that the Quora Terms of Service for writers, says the writer retain their ownership of copyrights, so I believe I'm allowed to republish my own writings.

Comment: Note that if you choose to post your content here on Stack Exchange, then you agree to license your content under Creative Commons, as explained at the bottom of every page.

Comment: That's alright. I'm fine with republications. That occurs on Quora also.

Answer (score 3):

No need to do anything special. You own the content, so you can post it here.